# scipy.optimize.minimize ignores constraint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize a linear function over one thousand variables. The constraints are: (w is numpy array, with element type float64)

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda w: 0.01 - abs(np.sum(w))},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda w: 1 - abs(np.sum(vMax0(w)))},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda w: 1 - abs(np.sum(vMin0(w)))})
```

where vMax0 and vMin0 are just vectorized function max(x,0) and min(x,0). The optimization statement is:

```
    w_raw = minimize(totalRisk, w0, bounds = wBounds, constraints = cons, 
                     method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})
```

But the optimal parameters are not even in the feasible region. Actually, the optimal parameters get out of feasible region after 1 or 2 iterations. What might be the possible reason for this? Thanks!

Comment: Are your constraints <= 1 and <= 0.01?

Comment: Your `cons` line isn't even syntactically valid. Please provide an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @rpattiso Basically, I want the sum of w's components to be close to 1 (<0.01), and the positive components has sum less than or equal to 1, and negative components has sum greater than or equal to -1.

Comment: @NPE The objective function is just a linear function. Thanks for pointing out the syntax error. The problem is that w keeps jumping out of the feasible region, which is kind of weird. Is there any other NL optimization packages in Python that's handy to use?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use a dedicated convex optimizer for this? Passing the constraints as functions makes the completely blackbox to the optimizer.

Comment: try http://www.cvxpy.org? I don't know much about it but it seems to have the correct pedigree.

Comment: @eickenberg Any recommended package (except the one Henry Gomersall mentioned) for convex optimizer? I'm using 32bit Python 2.7, thanks!

Comment: Would try cvxpy myself, too. Don't know any others for python.

Comment: @ErikaL What's wrong with cvxpy?

Comment: @HenryGomersall oops my reply "I'll check out cvxpy" disappears. It looks good but when I install it, it keeps saying it needs VC9.0, still struggling to make it work...

Comment: @HenryGomersall I believe there's something wrong in my C/C++ compiler setting so I can't install cvxpy. I've tried a lot of times and got frustrated. From cvxpy website it says Python(x,y) is recommended but I need to uninstall python first, which I'm reluctant to do.

Comment: @ErikaL Oh dear. Without the error message, I can't help you much. I suggest posting a new question. Compiling anything on windows is in my experience not a pleasant task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first constraint for sum makes `-0.01 <= sum(w) <= 0.01` which is not "close to 1".

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda w: 0.01 - abs(1 - np.sum(w))},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda w: 1 - abs(np.sum(vMax0(w)))},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda w: 1 - abs(np.sum(vMin0(w)))})
```

Now the absolute difference of the sum to one is no greater than 0.01 :)

Comment: sorry that was a typo -- I meant sum(w) should be close to 0 :(